# Full-text search in Postgres or CouchDB?

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, couchdb

I took geonames.org and imported all their data of German cities with all districts.

If I enter "Hamburg", it lists "Hamburg Center, Hamburg Airport" and so on. The application is in a closed network with no access to the internet, so I can't access the geonames.org web services and have to import the data. :(
The city with all of its districts works as an auto complete. So each key hit results in an XHR request and so on.

Now my customer asked whether it is possible to have all data of the world in it. Finally, about 5.000.000 rows with 45.000.000 alternative names etc.

Postgres needs about 3 seconds per query which makes the auto complete unusable.

Now I thought of CouchDb, have already worked with it. My question:

I would like to post "Ham" and I want CouchDB to get all documents starting with "Ham". If I enter "Hamburg" I want it to return Hamburg and so forth.

Is CouchDB the right database for it? Which other DBs can you recommend that respond with low latency (may be in-memory) and millions of datasets? The dataset doesn't change regularly, it's rather static!

Answer (score 19):

If I understand your problem right, probably all you need is already built in the CouchDB.

1. To get a range of documents with names beginning with e.g. "Ham". You may use a [request with a string range](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation?action=show&redirect=ViewCollation#String_Ranges): `startkey="Ham"&endkey="Ham\ufff0"`
2. If you need a more comprehensive search, you may create a view containing names of other places as keys. So you again can query ranges using the technique above.

Here is a view function to make this:

```
function(doc) {
    for (var name in doc.places) {
        emit(name, doc._id);
    }
}
```

Also see the CouchOne blog post about [CouchDB typeahead and autocomplete search](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920095142/http://couchio.tumblr.com/post/2314691278/couchdb-autocomplete) and this discussion on the mailing list about [CouchDB autocomplete](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201004.mbox/%3C7CA16887-7B02-46F6-A0EB-8CE6CE299892@gmail.com%3E).

Comment: +1 If you don't have CouchDB-Lucene installed yet, I would always try this technique first. It's not Lucene, but it's very easy and very flexible. I took the liberty of adding a helpful link to your answer.

Comment: One link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 18):

### Optimized search with PostgreSQL

Your search is **anchored at the start** and **no fuzzy search logic** is required. This  is **not** the typical use case for full text search.

If it gets more fuzzy or your search is *not* anchored at the start, look here for more:

- [Similar UTF-8 strings for autocomplete field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237366/similar-utf-8-strings-for-autocomplete-field/10238113#10238113)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

In PostgreSQL you can make use of **advanced index features** that should make the query **very fast**. In particular, look at [operator classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) and [indexes on expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html).

#### 1. `text_pattern_ops`

Assuming your column is of type text, you would use a special index for **text pattern operators** like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX name_text_pattern_ops_idx
ON tbl (name text_pattern_ops);

SELECT name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name ~~ ('Hambu' || '%');
```

This is assuming that you operate with a database locale other than `C` - most likely `de_DE.UTF-8` in your case. You *could* also set up a database with locale 'C'. I quote the [manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html):

> If you do use the C locale, you do not need the xxx_pattern_ops
> operator classes, because an index with the default operator class is
> usable for pattern-matching queries in the C locale.

Update: In modern Postgres consider `COLLATE "C"`. See:

- [Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291250/3684)

#### 2. Index on expression

I'd imagine you would also want to make that search **case insensitive**. so let's take another step and make that an index on an expression:

```sql
CREATE INDEX lower_name_text_pattern_ops_idx
ON tbl (lower(name) text_pattern_ops);

SELECT name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lower(name) ~~ (lower('Hambu') || '%');
```

To make use of the index, the `WHERE` clause has to match the the index expression.

#### 3. Optimize index size and speed

Finally, you might also want to impose a limit on the **number of leading characters** to minimize the size of your index and speed things up even further:

```sql
CREATE INDEX lower_left_name_text_pattern_ops_idx
ON tbl (lower(left(name,10)) text_pattern_ops);

SELECT name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lower(left(name,10)) ~~ (lower('Hambu') || '%');
```

`left()` was introduced with Postgres 9.1. Use [`substring(name, 1,10)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) in older versions.

#### 4. Cover all possible requests

What about strings with more than 10 characters?

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lower(left(name,10)) ~~ (lower(left('Hambu678910',10)) || '%');
AND    lower(name) ~~ (lower('Hambu678910') || '%');
```

This looks redundant, but you need to spell it out this way to actually use the index. Index search will narrow it down to a few entries, the additional clause filters the rest. Experiment to find the sweet spot. Depends on data distribution and typical use cases. 10 characters seem like a good starting point. For more than 10 characters, `left()` effectively turns into a very fast and simple hashing algorithm that's good enough for many (but not all) use cases.

Update: in modern Postgres consider the `^@` operator instead. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

#### 5. Optimize disk representation with `CLUSTER`

So, the predominant access pattern will be to retrieve a bunch of adjacent rows according to our index `lower_left_name_text_pattern_ops_idx`. And you **mostly read and hardly ever write**. This is a **textbook case for `CLUSTER`**. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html):

> When a table is clustered, it is physically reordered based on the index information.

With a huge table like yours, this can dramatically improve response time because all rows to be fetched are in the same or adjacent blocks on disk.

First call:

```
CLUSTER tbl USING lower_left_name_text_pattern_ops_idx;
```

Information which index to use will be saved and successive calls will re-cluster the table:

```
CLUSTER tbl;
CLUSTER;    -- cluster all tables in the db that have previously been clustered.
```

If you don't want to repeat it:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl SET WITHOUT CLUSTER;
```

However, `CLUSTER` takes an exclusive lock on the table. If that's a problem, look into [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/) or [`pg_squeeze`](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze), which can do the same without exclusive lock on the table.

#### 6. Prevent too many rows in the result

Demand a minimum of, say, 3 or 4 characters for the search string. I add this for completeness, you probably do it anyway.
And `LIMIT` the number of rows returned:

```
SELECT name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lower(left(name,10)) ~~ (lower('Hambu') || '%')
LIMIT  501;
```

If your query returns more than 500 rows, tell the user to narrow down his search.

#### 7. Optimize filter method (operators)

If you absolutely must squeeze out every last microsecond, you can utilize operators of the [`text_pattern_ops` family](https://www.leadum.com/downloads/dbscribe/samples/postgresql/web_modern/opclass/main/797981622.html). Like this:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lower(left(name, 10)) ~>=~ lower('Hambu')
AND    lower(left(name, 10)) ~<=~ (lower('Hambu') || chr(2097151));
```

You gain very little with this last stunt. Normally, standard operators are the better choice.

---

**If you do all that, search time will be reduced to a matter of milliseconds.**

Comment: in `Cover all possible requests` first tilde operator should be `tilde tilde`?

Comment: @jian: Yes, thanks, that was a typo!

Answer (score 10):

I think a better approach is keep your data on your database (Postgres or CouchDB) and index it with a full-text search engine, like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Having said that, there's a [project integrating CouchDB with Lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene).

Comment: +1 When you search text, nothing competes with a full-text search index.