# postgres: fulltext search: fastest way to find duplicate text rows?

Tags: postgresql

:-)

What is the fastest way to find duplicate texts in a table, i.e., rows in a table that has a text in one column that occurs at least twice in the whole table? The table contains over 160 million rows.

I have a table that consists of the columns: `id`, `maintext`, and `maintext_token`, where the latter was created with `to_tsvector(maintext);`. Moreover, I created a GIN index on `maintext_token`, i.e., `create index idx_maintext_tokens on tablename using gin(maintext_token);`

Currently, I'm using the following, which - however - takes a rather long time:
I have a table that consists of the columns: `id`, `maintext`, and `maintext_token`, where the latter was created with `to_tsvector(maintext);`. Moreover, I created a GIN index on `maintext_token`, i.e., `create index idx_maintext_tokens on tablename using gin(maintext_token);`

```
select maintext, count(maintext)
from ccnc
group by maintext
having count(maintext)>1
order by maintext;
```

I also tried to do the same operation, but instead of using `maintext` I use the `maintext_token` column for the comparison:

```
select maintext_token, count(maintext_token)
from ccnc
group by maintext_token
having count(maintext_token)>1
order by maintext_token;
```

Both queries seem to run long, even though I was expecting at least the second query to be much faster, since postgres can use the index for comparison.

Thank you in advance for any insights!
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to test for equality, so you might want to hash the text, and then search on the hashes. You can do this with a hash index, or you can index a hash of the text. I got some help recently on a related question, you'll find details and comparisons here:

[Searching on expression indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002565/searching-on-expression-indexes)